# How to format dates in microsoft access queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)
```

In Microsoft SQL Server, the above query returns the current date in the format

> mm/dd/yyyy - 05/01/2014

What is its Microsoft Access query equivalent? I have tried `CDate(MyDateValue)` but this does not retain leading zeroes. In the example above, it returns

> 5/1/2014

but i need the leading zeroes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try using

`format`

```
select Format (#05/01/2014#, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

[more info here](http://webcheatsheet.com/SQL/access_functions/format.php)

Answer (score -2):

Try this
select convert(date,getdate(),101)