# Call a cell inside of an active form, in Microsoft Access

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

I'm designing a database in Access, I've made a form for data entry.
In Excel there is a feature were it's possible to enter the formula:
=Text(CELL,"FORMAT")

Is this possible to do in Access, inside of an open form.

What I want is for a user to enter a date inside the form, and then another text box inside the same form autofills the value of the month, that is sourced from the date.

[image: Image of what I to do in Access, done in Excel]

I tried changing the default value of the month field with the location of the date field in the form:
Default Value =[Forms]![frm_Train_Faults]![Date]

The table is already formatted to force dates in the month column to be "MMM".

I expected it to work like in Excel, similar to referencing a cell.  It didn't work sadly.

Comment: You can do this in the properties tab when opening the form in design mode. Under *Data >> Control Source* insert the following: `=Format([YourControlName],"mmm")`. Just change the name of the control so Access knows where to look.

Comment: @KostasK. THANK YOU!  The solution worked, and you've helped me massively.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format dates in microsoft access queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624859/how-to-format-dates-in-microsoft-access-queries)

Comment: Options: 1) calc in table or query used as form RecordSource then bind textbox to calculated field, 2) calc in textbox.